# Bean not found by its interface after migration to WildFly

Tags: java, jboss, cdi, wildfly, bean-manager

After the migration of a JEE application (from JBoss 7.1.1 to WildFly 8.2.1) our method to get CDI Beans stopped working. The application have several modules (independent JAR files) grouped into one WAR file deployed now on WildFly.

The Bean to be injected is in the module `service` and it is implementing the interface `IProcessor`:

```
@Loggable
@Monitorable
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(CONTAINER)
@Lock(READ)
@LocalBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class Processor implements IProcessor {
[...]
```

In another module of the application (`common`) there is the rest of the logic: the interface `IProcessor` and the class where we search for it.

This is how the BeanManager is retrieved:

```
public void keepBeanManager(@Observes AfterBeanDiscovery abd, BeanManager beanManager) {
    bm = beanManager;
}
```

And this is how the call is done:

```
Set<Bean<?>> jobBeans = bm.getBeans(IProcessor.class);
```

I've tried printing out all deployed beans using Adam Bien's [sample](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_discover_all_deployed),  at the same point as the `getBeans` method is called, and I can see the `Processor` in them. Also, if providing the full package and class name of the `Processor` works as a temporal hack, but using the `IProcessor` interface never works, `jobBeans` is always empty.

The module `service` is not visible to the module `common`, and this is why the injection is done using the interface.

As it was working before in JBoss and not in WildFly I assume it is related with the way the AS is handling the Beans, could it be something missing in the configuration of WildFly after the migration?

Comment: Did you try without the @LocalBean?

Comment: Does each JAR have a `beans.xml`?

Comment: @JohnAment Yes, each JAR has a beans.xml

Comment: @XavierDury That worked! Removing the LocalBean fixed the issue. I've been reading that LocalBean is used only when bean has a no-interface view. So I guess this was wrong all the time as the Processor is exposed through the interface IProcessor. I wonder why it did work on JBoss. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by Xavier Dury in the comments, the Bean was not found because it was annotated as `@LocalBean`. Removing the `@LocalBean` annotation fixed the issue.

From the [JEE definition of LocalBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/LocalBean.html):

> Designates that a session bean exposes a no-interface view

As `Processor` is implementing the interface `IProcessor`, the annotation `@LocalBean` should not be used.

What is strange still for me is why this was working on JBoss...